# Symbolic computation in finite fields

Tags: cryptanalysis, algebraic-attack

What I want to know is how to perform symbolic finite field computations in SAGE math? Such computations are required in building algebraic models for cryptanalysis. To explain this mathematically consider the finite field GF($2^n$). If I am given the irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ and $a$ its root which generates the extension field, then any indeterminate $x$ in this field is represented in polynomial basis
$x=x_0+x_1a+x_2a^2+...+x_{(n-1)}a^{(n-1)}$
where $x_i$ are indeterminate co-ordinates. How do I declare such an indeterminates $x, y$ and find the co-ordinates in the basis of functions such as $x^2$,$xy$ etc. in terms of their symbolic co-ordinates in SAGE?

Comment: Do you know there is a [ask.sagemath](https://ask.sagemath.org/) similar to this site?

Comment: This is a programming question, almost off topic and with zero effort on poster's part.